# Proving that a map is an isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am reading Fraleigh and I am having trouble understanding the proof to this Lemma. It is my understanding that to prove that a map is an isomorphism, we must prove that it is a *bijective* homomorphism. I think the first half of this proof shows that the map is a homomorphism when the binary operation is addition and when the binary operation is multiplication. Then, Fraleigh has shown that the map is 1-1 but has now shown that the map is onto. **Isn't this proof incomplete? What am I missing?**

[image]

Comment: The text says that $D$ is isomorphic to the image of $i$, a subring of $F$.

Comment: What is $D$ and $F$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ihf notes, surjectivity is essentially "by choice", since Fraleigh restricts to $i[D]$.